# Looking for an efficient way in Haskell to use Data.Vector to create a vector with unique entries that hold duplicate entries from a source vector

Tags: haskell, vector

The ultimate goal is to make a HashMap. In the exploratory code below the vector of indices has a duplicate index. This can happen in the real data I am working with.

An exploratory example is given below. The data specified in "vec" has a string value for every index. In real data this is a data structure with a number of fields. The result I am needing is shown as "desiredResult" which has a list of values for each index value.

Data.Vector has a filter function that does not give me what I am needing to iterate over every index value in one Vector to filter values in another vector.

```
module VectorTest
  where

-- vector

import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector

indices = Vector.fromList [1,2,3,3,4,5]

vec = Vector.fromList [(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c"), (3,"d"), (4,"e"),(5,"f")]

{-
 How to make this result in the most efficient way
-}

desiredResult = Vector.fromList [(1,["a"]),(2,["b"]),(3,["c","d"]), (4,["e"]),(5,["f"])]
```

Exploring the use of index functions as shown below:

```
indexOccurrences <- Vector.forM indices $ \ index -> ( Vector.findIndices (\ n  -> (fst n ) == index  ) vec )
```

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I will be updating this post with the solutions I am building. The intent is to share knowledge on how to get the most efficient way to code this for large vectors.

Comment: Is your vector of indices sorted?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard The close reason for that is "Needs focus". It's too broad because it's asking how to accomplish a large goal, instead of looking for help with a sub-goal that's not working.

Comment: @luqui yes the indices can be sorted.

Comment: The obvious method is to fold into an intmap then build the vector from that. You can save a bit of space by using an intset but then you iterate over the input twice. If the indices are guaranteed to be sequential then your life is easier because you know upfront the output vector size. Reverse iteration over the input might make it easier to efficiently build the result you want in a mutable vector (because then you encounter the items in a suitable order for consing onto the output lists).

Comment: use Map, building it with [`foldl (\map (k,a) ->  insertWith (++) k [a] map) empty`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=insertWith) over your assoc-list, or something similar.